# AWS inter-subnet routing issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a VPC ( say vpc-a ) with CIDR range 192.170.0.0/16 .

I have created 3 subnets in the VPC which are as follows:

```
   > aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-05d932bbfd4bfe3c5
    {
        "Subnets": [
            {
                "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1b",
                "AvailabilityZoneId": "aps1-az3",
                "AvailableIpAddressCount": 57,
                "CidrBlock": "192.170.80.0/26",
                "DefaultForAz": false,
                "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
                "State": "available",
                "SubnetId": "subnet-0a4c7cc6faa094318",
                "VpcId": "vpc-05d932bbfd4bfe3c5",
                "OwnerId": "336282279309",
                "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
                "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
                "Tags": [
                    ...
                ],
                "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:336282279309:subnet/subnet-0a4c7cc6faa094318"
            },
            {
                "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a",
                "AvailabilityZoneId": "aps1-az1",
                "AvailableIpAddressCount": 48,
                "CidrBlock": "192.170.0.0/26",
                "DefaultForAz": false,
                "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
                "State": "available",
                "SubnetId": "subnet-0b6e7a1e1840713a9",
                "VpcId": "vpc-05d932bbfd4bfe3c5",
                "OwnerId": "336282279309",
                "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
                "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
                "Tags": [
                    ...
                ],
                "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:336282279309:subnet/subnet-0b6e7a1e1840713a9"
            },
            {
                "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1c",
                "AvailabilityZoneId": "aps1-az2",
                "AvailableIpAddressCount": 49,
                "CidrBlock": "192.170.160.0/26",
                "DefaultForAz": false,
                "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
                "State": "available",
                "SubnetId": "subnet-0e45e8fc489794ea9",
                "VpcId": "vpc-05d932bbfd4bfe3c5",
                "OwnerId": "336282279309",
                "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
                "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
                "Tags": [
                    ...
                ],
                "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:336282279309:subnet/subnet-0e45e8fc489794ea9"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So basically 3 subnets are:

```
subnet-0   CIDR: 192.170.0.0/26    Zone: ap-south-1a
subnet-1   CIDR: 192.170.80.0/26   Zone: ap-south-1b
subnet-2   CISR: 192.170.160.0/26  Zone: ap-south-1c
```

The route tables are as follows:

```
 aws ec2 describe-route-tables --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-05d932bbfd4bfe3c5
{
    "RouteTables": [
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "Main": true,
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-02f438a98c50824f2",
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-04a14541aaf44b1d1",
                    "AssociationState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "PropagatingVgws": [],
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-04a14541aaf44b1d1",
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.170.0.0/16",
                    "GatewayId": "local",
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable",
                    "State": "active"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [],
            "VpcId": "vpc-05d932bbfd4bfe3c5",
            "OwnerId": "336282279309"
        },
        {
            "Associations": [
                {
                    "Main": false,
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-047cce5bf22b50a76",
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-08371ccc1f79ebfe6",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-0e45e8fc489794ea9",
                    "AssociationState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Main": false,
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-0fbf237d4b7af1b57",
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-08371ccc1f79ebfe6",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-0a4c7cc6faa094318",
                    "AssociationState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Main": false,
                    "RouteTableAssociationId": "rtbassoc-066c66d94f1aa32a5",
                    "RouteTableId": "rtb-08371ccc1f79ebfe6",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-0b6e7a1e1840713a9",
                    "AssociationState": {
                        "State": "associated"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "PropagatingVgws": [],
            "RouteTableId": "rtb-08371ccc1f79ebfe6",
            "Routes": [
                {
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.168.0.0/24",
                    "TransitGatewayId": "tgw-065d7ae5e846681b0",
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute",
                    "State": "active"
                },
                {
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "192.170.0.0/16",
                    "GatewayId": "local",
                    "Origin": "CreateRouteTable",
                    "State": "active"
                },
                {
                    "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "GatewayId": "igw-0d37c7db290bf696c",
                    "Origin": "CreateRoute",
                    "State": "active"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "wqw"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-05d932bbfd4bfe3c5",
            "OwnerId": "336282279309"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have 2 ec2 instances :

```
instance-1  Subnet: subnet-0 ,  IP :  192.170.0.57
instance-2  Subnet: subnet-1 ,  IP :  192.170.80.6
```

I am unable to do ssh from instance-1 to instance-2 or vice-varsa. However I am able to ssh to both of them from another instance in another vpc with cidr 192.168.0.0/16 using transit gateway, which you may find in the routing information above.

Do I need to add additional routing info between the subnets subnet-0 & subnet-1 ? If so what would be the "target" of such route ? I tried enabling flow-log on the vpc but nothing came in cloud-watch logs.

Appreciate some help here.

Comment: How do you know that its routing problem, and not security groups for example?

Comment: @Marcin , yes just found out and was about to write an answer. The security group rules allowed ssh traffic from 192.168.0.0/24 only. I had to specifically add another rule for ssh between instances in the same vpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local VPC route will always be allowed so this is not a routing issue.

Check the following:

- Security Groups
- NACLs.

Also take a look at [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) and enable on both subnets. Look for REJECTs.

Comment: Yes,  just found out and was about to write an answer. The security group rules allowed ssh traffic from 192.168.0.0/24 only. I had to specifically add another rule for ssh between instances in the same vpc